# Election candidates lacking details in their manifestos

Tags: discussion, moderation, election, moderators

Elections on most sites have the candidate's individual manifestos, as [here on Veganism and Vegetarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/election).

In addition, every site where I've voted in an election has shown the candidates' answers to various sample questions: "What would you do if a user who contributes good answers were to frequently get flagged for their comments being inappropriate for respectful discourse?" - questions of that type which show the type of moderator that the candidate is likely to be - or at least wishes to become.

Not here however.

**Question:**

What was the basis for the decision to omit these questions and answers for the candidates in this election?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Veganism & Vegetarianism is still in Beta. As such this is a [Pro Tempore Election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections) and if you read that question from Meta Stack Exchange it has the following text:

> For these elections, the candidate questionnaire is an optional feature that individual sites can choose if they want (example [here](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3708/2637)). If sites choose not to have a questionnaire, we encourage voters to ask their questions on the site's meta use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags. Moderator candidates should monitor meta for these questions.

So I guess you just ask your question here if you have one.

Comment: Leaving a comment so that I can also be pinged here with any questions.